# Issue with loading a React page that takes much time to load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-markdown

I have a react application that uses React router. One of the pages loads big data and converts it to markdown content. The problem is this page also contains many other components so if the markdown component loads big data it gives me this error in the browser:
[image].

This is the code of the page:

```
export default function SingleEntry (props){

    const [theEntry, setTheEntry] = React.useState()
    const [theSearchedEntry, setTheSearchedEntry] = React.useState()
    const [searched, setSearched] = React.useState(false)
    
     React.useEffect(function(){
                fetch('/entries/' + props.id)
                // fetch('/entries/' + 4)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                setTheEntry(`${data.body}`)
                setTheTitle(`${data.title}`)
             

                },[])
   
React.useEffect(function () {

  // if (loaded){
  setHeadings([])
  const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("h2, h3, h4"))
      .filter((element) => element.id)
      .map((element) => ({
        id: element.id,
        text: element.textContent ?? "",
        level: Number(element.tagName.substring(1))
      }
      ));
  setHeadings(elements);
  

// }

}, [theEntry])


//...other functions 
  

 return (
        
        //....other components
       
        <div id="SEforpdf" className="SE">
  
    <ReactMarkdown
      components={{
        h2: ({ node, ...props }) => (
          <h2 id={`${props.children[0]}`} {...props}></h2>
        ),
        h3: ({ node, ...props }) => (
          <h3 id={`${props.children[0]}`} {...props}></h3>
        ),
        h4: ({ node, ...props }) => (
          <h4 id={`${props.children[0]}`}  {...props}></h4>
        ),
        h5: ({ node, ...props }) => (
          <h5 id={`${props.children[0]}`} {...props}></h5>
        ),
        h6: ({ node, ...props }) => (
          <h6 id={`${props.children[0]}`} {...props}></h6>
        ),
      }}
     
      children={searched ? theSearchedEntry : theEntry}
    />
  </div>

    )
}
```

The solution that I have tried to use is React lazy for the route
App.js:

```
<Routes>
   <Route path='/entry/:entryId' element={<EntryPrivateRoute  />}/>
</Routes>
```

EntryPrivateRoute.js:

```
const SingleEntry = lazy(() => import('../components/SingleEntry'));

const EntryPrivateRoute = () => {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false)
    let {user} = useContext(AuthContext)
    const params = useParams();
    React.useEffect(function(){
        fetch('/entries/' + params.entryId)
        setLoaded(true)
    })
    },[])
   
    if (loaded){
       
        if (user != null){
                 return user.approved  ?  <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}><SingleEntry id={params.entryId} /></Suspense> : <Navigate to="/login" />
        }
        else{
            return(
            <Navigate to="/login" />
            )
        }
    }
}

export default EntryPrivateRoute;
```

This solution hasn't worked for me and lazy is not working so how can I solve it whether by adjusting lazy component or use another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue seems to be related to the first `useEffect` you have in `SingleEntry`, it has no dependency array so the callback function is executed at every render.

If you want the run the `useEffect` callback to run once the component is renedered the first time, so a single time, chenge it as the following:

```
React.useEffect(function () {
     fetch('/entries/' + props.id)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
               setTheEntry(`${data.body}`)
               setTheTitle(`${data.title}`)
          })
     }
, [])
```

Comment: This was a writing mistake in the question but it was written in the code